# After deploying war files to tomcat, webapp does not show new changes

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, war

I have a maven project that uses spring framework. So when I deploy, I have to build new .war files by running `mvn clean install -P LOCAL`, This will create new .war files. Then I copy these war files to tomcat directory under webapps. The problem is when I access the app through localhose:8080, I don't see the changes. What am I doning wrong?

EDIT:

It's the UI .war file that does not update. Other war files does show changes. So all changes to UI are not showing. I tried clearing cache, but it did'nt work (ctrl + f5 does not work too).

Comment: have you restarted the Tomcat application, right? Try also deleting the "work" folder

Comment: thats the pain with tomcat mate.... try clearing the directory before updating war and also restart is a must

Comment: I restarted tomcat, and deleted "work" folder, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you as steps for deploying on tomcat:

1. Stop tomcat application or service
2. Go to your `webapp` folder (the one related to your project), and remove all files from it (both .war and extracted files)
3. Delete the `work` folder from tomcat root path
4. Copy your `.war` file to your webapp folder
5. Restart Tomcat

A tip: you can easly autodeploy your app with Maven by using a plugin , you can find all info [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html). With this you can easly run `tomcat7:redeploy` , he will take care of the dirt and the deploy operations :)

Answer (score 2):

You can go to http://localhost:8080/manager/ and try to re-deploy your war.

Try to clear your tomcat directory and copy the fresh war files.